# Set background image of a Tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

I have set the background image of a `Tabhost` but image is not fitting on it
It is starting from half of each `TabWidget`
I have tried my best but could not get rid of this 
Kindly help !

the code for my xml is

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/back"
      >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

snap shot of current app is

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6519/captureyha.png

Answer (score 1):

where you want to start it from ?

**Edit:** Try This.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/back"
      >


<TabHost
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#000"
      >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: from the start of tab ofcourse, I want the drawable to fit the screen

Comment: I dont't want that space coming before the background image

Comment: What if you put the 'TabHost' inside 'RelativeLayout' and set the background of 'RelativeLayout'.

Comment: image is correct 100 % its a png and its size is as the size of screen, I have also made it run without the tabhost thing.. It works perfectly fine